# ExceptionsManager.js:76 TypeError: this.state.albums.map is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I kept getting this error on this line

> return this.state.albums.map(album => album.title);

Which I don't think I did anything wrong there.

This is my entire code

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import axios from 'axios';

class AlbumList extends Component {

    state = { albums: [] }; 

    componentWillMount() {
        axios.get('https://rallycoding.herokuapp.com/api/music_albums')
            .then(response => this.setState({ albums: response }));
    }

    renderAlbums() {
        return this.state.albums.map(album => <Text>album.title</Text>);
    }

    render() { 
        // console.log(this.state);
        return <View>{ this.renderAlbums() }</View>;
    }
}

export default AlbumList;
```

Is there anything that I missed ?

Comment: In addition to @Jacob's answer which solves your main problem here you need to use `<Text>{album.title}</Text>` to get the titles. In JSX you need to use curly braces to use a JS expression. Also, in the future if you bound this renderAlbums function to a button or anything else that uses a callback either bind your function in the constructor or use an arrow function.

Comment: I still get the same error message https://pasteboard.co/HtSauQn.png

Comment: This means you are doing something wrong again. Here is a working example: https://codesandbox.io/s/6vyy802ypr

Comment: I added the `.data` and the `{}` as suggested. My code now look like this. https://jsfiddle.net/bheng/cz0ue3k5/

Comment: I'm not accustomed to Jsfiddle for React. You can see suggested code in the accepted answer works flawlessly on my example on codesandbox.

Answer (score 1):

`axios.get` yields a [*response* object](https://github.com/axios/axios#response-schema), not the contents of the response body. To access that, use `response.data`.

```
class AlbumList extends Component {
  // ...
  componentWillMount() {
    axios.get('https://rallycoding.herokuapp.com/api/music_albums')
        .then(response => this.setState({ albums: response.data }));
  }
  // ...
}
```

The fact that you were setting `this.state.albums` to the response is the reason why it's not an `Array`.

Comment: I still get the same error message with your suggestion. https://pasteboard.co/HtSauQn.png

Comment: By the way, I think you edited the answer accidentally. I've fixed for you but try not to edit the answers.

Comment: @kyo: are you sure that the data coming back is an Array? You ought to post that detail to the question, what the shape of the response data looks like.